# Limit of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let be $(x_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ a sequence of real numbers, so $x_{0}=a\in (-1,1), x_{1}=\sqrt{\frac{1+a}{2}}, 2x_{n+2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-x_{n}}{1+x_{n+1}}},n\geq 0.$ Find $ \lim_{n \to \infty }x_{n} and \lim_{n \to \infty } 2^{n}(1-x_{n}^{2}).$

I've considered a=cos(x),and afterwards $x_{1}=\left| \cos \dfrac {x}{2}\right| $ and I'm stuck here.

Comment: Assuming that $\{x_n\}$ has a limit $L$, your recursive formula for $x_{n+2}$ gives $2 L = \sqrt{(1-L)/(1+L)}$. This leads to $4L^3 + 4L^2 + L - 1 = 0$ which doesn't have a particularly nice root.  It is, however, in between $0$ and $1/2$ so that the second limit is infinite.

Comment: Why don't you try first to see if the fixed point equation $2L=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-L}{1+L}}$ has "candidate solutions" ?

Comment: So, it is not possible to calculate the limit of these sequence?We can say only that the limit is between 1 and1/2. I've thought I can find the formula of general term, but it is possible that I was wrong.